# PHP and MySQL fckeditor integration?

Tags: php, mysql, fckeditor

I just downloaded [FCKeditor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CKEditor) and dropped the folder into my root directory, but I don't know how to install the FCKeditor into my forms. For example, I wanted to integrate the FCKeditor into the About Me and My Interests form fields in the form below, but I don't know how or even how to change the fckeditor skins. How do I do this?

I'm using PHP and MySQL.

Here is the HTML.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="about-me">About Me: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="about-me" id="about-me"></textarea></li>

            <li><label for="my-interests">My Interests: </label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="interests" id="interests"></textarea></li>

            <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes" class="save-button" />
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the Php  it's very easy

```
<?php
include_once(“fckeditor/fckeditor.php”) ;

$sBasePath = $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ;                                                       
$oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1') ;                                                   
$oFCKeditor->BasePath = 'fckeditor/' ;                                                       
$oFCKeditor->ToolbarSet = 'Basic';                                                            
$oFCKeditor->Height = 200;                                                                     
$oFCKeditor->Width  = 400;                                                                     
$oFCKeditor->Value = '<p>Now the FCKeditor is available and ready to use. So, just insert the        following code in your p</p>' ;
$oFCKeditor->Create() ;


?>
```

Put this code in your html.

For more details go to an article in my blog: [Basic FCKEditor Integration](http://sandeepshirsat.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/13/)

Answer (score 1):

For example I do next action:

First write on  section that code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Second

```
<textarea cols="80" id="FCKeditor1" name="FCKeditor1" rows="10"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'FCKeditor1',{
        toolbar : 'Full',
        skin:'kama'
    } );
</script>
```

after that action I saw on my browser ckeditor.

Answer (score 0):

*[FCKeditor 2.x, Developers Guide, PHP](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/PHP)* is a good guide on integrated FCKeditor into PHP. You include the file, create an object, assign some parameters and you're good to go. It's pretty easy and useful.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

CKEdit is just a JavaScript plugin. In order to use it with PHP and MySQL you don't really need to take any specific precautions. You can just follow the guide: *[FCKeditor 2.x, Developers Guide, JavaScript](http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/JavaScript)*.

Head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fckeditor/fckeditor.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FCKeditor1');
    oFCKeditor.BasePath = "/fckeditor/";
    oFCKeditor.Create();
</script>
```

Where you replace: "FCKeditor1" in the above example with "about-me", and again for your "interests" field.